# Loading bitmap image in c++ thread

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap

I am attempting to load in a selected .bmp file and display it in WM_PAINT. The function is being ran by the code so visual studio does see it.
here is the code that seems to be not working:

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    _hWindowDC = BeginPaint(_hwnd, &ps);

    if (g_bIsFileLoaded)
    {
        std::wstring wsFileName = g_vecImageFileNames.back();
        g_vecImageFileNames.pop_back();

        std::string File(wsFileName.length(), ' ');
        std::copy(wsFileName.begin(), wsFileName.end(), File.begin());

        HBITMAP h_BitMap = (HBITMAP)LoadImageA(g_hInstance, File.c_str(), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
        HDC h_HomeDC = CreateCompatibleDC(_hWindowDC);
        BITMAP BitMap;

        int i_Final = GetObject(reinterpret_cast<HGDIOBJ>(h_BitMap), sizeof(BITMAP), reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(&BitMap));

        HBITMAP h_OldBit = (HBITMAP)::SelectObject(h_HomeDC, h_BitMap);

        SetStretchBltMode(_hWindowDC, HALFTONE);

        BOOL PaintBit = StretchBlt(_hWindowDC, 1, 1, 50, 50, h_HomeDC, 0, 0, BitMap.bmWidth, BitMap.bmHeight, SRCCOPY);

        ::SelectObject(h_HomeDC, h_OldBit);
        ::DeleteDC(h_HomeDC);
        ::DeleteObject(h_BitMap);

        InvalidateRect(_hwnd, NULL, NULL);

        g_bIsFileLoaded = false;
    }

    EndPaint(_hwnd, &ps);
    return (0);
}
break;
```

Comment: What do you mean by `seems to be not working`? Do you get a specific error message?

Comment: No, just no image is loaded and it just shows a white background

Comment: Does this code run in a separate thread?

Comment: You paint the bitmap once, and then no more. Further you inactivate the window after painting which defeats the point of painting. Your job there is to make the window valid!

Comment: You also do no error checking whatsoever, so perhaps you don't even manage to paint the bitmap once. Perhaps you never even manage to load it. Anyway, you have to understand `WM_PAINT` better. It gets called repeatedly. Your job is to paint the window ever time it fires, not just once. I suggest that you revisit your Win32 tutorial, or buy Petzold's book.